# How do I setup Hyperledger fabric chaincode java api?

Tags: java, gradle

This is my first time working with blockchain technology of any kind, and I am new to this space, I've been trying to set it up for days, following the documentation
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/getting_started.html but I am stuck here:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java

```
./gradlew clean build install
```

this , always results in this,

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'install' not found in root project 'fabric-chaincode-java'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

I tried setting up gradle, i tried making some changes in dependencies, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided error message, it seems that the task 'install' is unknown. I am not clearly sure what you are going to achieve, but if it is only about building the project you can simply run: `gradle clean build` or `./gradlew clean build`. Even `gradle build` or `./gradlew build` should do the job.